# Exception writing an ArrayList to File

Tags: java

I am having a problem writing an `ArrayList` to a `File` in java. The program below is saving an error to the file instead of the data I am trying to save.

Below is the code I am using. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

```
package mytracker;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ExportContacts 
{
    private ObjectOutputStream OP;

    private void openFileOut(String path)
    {
        try
        {
            OP = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path + ".dat"));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void AddContacts(List<Contact> contacts)
    {
        try
        {
            for(int i=0;i<contacts.size();i++)
            {
                OP.writeObject(contacts.get(i));
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void CloseFileOut()
    {
        try 
        {
            if(OP!=null)
                OP.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void ExportConacts(String path,List<Contact> contacts)
    {
        openFileOut(path);
        AddContacts(contacts);
        CloseFileOut();
    }
}
```

---

```
private void ExportButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
{
    try
    {             
        JFileChooser fileChooser=new JFileChooser();
        //fileChooser.setFileFilter(new filter());
        fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
        int result=fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this);

        if(result!=JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION)
        {
            String path= fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
            ExportContacts ex=new ExportContacts();
            //CL is object of the class that save the contacts
            List<Contact> c=CL.getContactsList();
            ex.ExportConacts(path, c);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Contacts Exported Successfully !");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: What type of `Exception` is thrown?

Comment: The error message in the file could be useful.

Comment: My crystal ball says **Contact** doesn't implement the **java.io.Serializable** interface.

Comment: @maurício Could well be, don't know without that code or the exception/error message.

Comment: @Omar - Welcome to stackoverflow. In future, be sure to include the error message and stacktrace. If people have to guess, it will take much longer to answer your question ;)

Answer (score 2):

A. `Contact` must implement `Serializable` (you haven't shown code for `Contact`)
B. Don't serialize each `Contact`, just serialize the whole `List`

Comment: I guess you must have a very reliable crystal ball?